Restrict responses from a language model (LLM) to only information available in a specific document
I'm looking for a method to ensure that responses from an LLM are only provided when the information is available in VectorDB. I've experimented with various prompts but still find it challenging to assess the relevance of VectorDB search results. Most of the time, VectorDB retrieves something, and it's hard to evaluate how relevant the search results are.
One way I found is by using the LLM to determine how close the search query matches the search results. Any suggestions on how to implement this effectively or other strategies to ensure the LLM only responds when the information is available in VectorDB?
